# es6 filter JSON returns undefined, filter object does not

Tags: javascript, json, ecmascript-6

I have a filter function that is returning undefined only when JSON is passed into it. I'd like to use this function to filter objects, JSON or anything really. Whats the best way to make this work on both objects and JSON?

```js
let a = [{
  "employees": {
    "employee": [{
      "id": "1",
      "firstName": "Tom",
      "lastName": "Cruise"
    }, {
      "id": "2",
      "firstName": "Maria",
      "lastName": "Sharapova"
    }, {
      "id": "3",
      "firstName": "James",
      "lastName": "Bond"
    }]
  }
}];

var b = [{
  name: '',
  grade: 'x'
}, {
  name: 'yaya',
  grade: 'x'
}, {
  name: 'x',
  frade: 'd'
}, {
  name: 'a',
  grade: 'b'
}];

function findIt(arr, searchKey) {
  return arr.filter(obj => Object.keys(obj).some(key => obj[key].includes(searchKey)));
}

if (a) {
  console.log("I found: ", findIt(a, "James")); // breaks
}

if (b) {
  console.log("I found: ", findIt(b, "yaya")); // works fine
}
```

Comment: I don't see any [JSON](http://json.org/) in your script; [What is the difference between JSON and Object Literal Notation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2904131/what-is-the-difference-between-json-and-object-literal-notation)

Comment: There's no JSON there, you have an array. A function written for a certain structure won't magically work for any structure, or in this case, nesting?

Comment: `obj[key]` is an object and object does not have `includes` property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a reference to the inner array for searching.

```
findIt(a[0].employees.employee, "James"));
//      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

```js
let a = [{ employees: { employee: [{ id: "1", firstName: "Tom", lastName: "Cruise" }, { id: "2", firstName: "Maria", lastName: "Sharapova" }, { id: "3", firstName: "James", lastName: "Bond" }] } }];
var b = [{ name: '', grade: 'x' }, { name: 'yaya', grade: 'x' }, { name: 'x', frade: 'd' }, { name: 'a', grade: 'b' }];

function findIt(arr, searchKey) {
    return arr.filter(obj => Object.keys(obj).some(key => obj[key].includes(searchKey)));
}

console.log(findIt(a[0].employees.employee, "James"));
console.log(findIt(b, "yaya"));
```

For a deeper find, you could use an recursive approach.

```js
function findIt(object, search) {
    function find(k) {
        if (object[k] === search) {
            return result = object;
        }
        return result = findIt(object[k], search);
    }

    var result;
    if (object && typeof object === 'object') {
        Object.keys(object).some(find);
    }
    return result;
}


var a = [{ employees: { employee: [{ id: "1", firstName: "Tom", lastName: "Cruise" }, { id: "2", firstName: "Maria", lastName: "Sharapova" }, { id: "3", firstName: "James", lastName: "Bond" }] } }],
    b = [{ name: '', grade: 'x' }, { name: 'yaya', grade: 'x' }, { name: 'x', frade: 'd' }, { name: 'a', grade: 'b' }];

console.log(findIt(a, "James"));
console.log(findIt(b, "yaya"));
console.log(findIt(a, "foo"));   // undefined
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Hi @nina Scholz Does it have to be accessed like: a[0].employees.employee ?

Comment: I can't just search the whole tree?

Comment: You will have to recursively check inside tree. You can use this as a **[sample](https://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/dLfLn23q/)**

Comment: the reason I say this as its a redux store, I'm not entirely sure about the structure of the object / json.

Comment: @Jimi A simple question, If you need to search entire tree, *Why  use `.filter`*. This will return you lot more data than expected

Comment: its a good point @Rajesh, what's a more performant option then?

Comment: it depends what you need, the first array with the values where a match is found or all finds at every depth?

Comment: I'm really only look at matching one property. But the json is nested.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to do a string search.

#### Logic

- Create a copy of object but as string using `JSON.stringify`
- Create a regex that  searches for a pattern `:<something>SearchValue`.
- Test object string with this regex and return it in filter

```js
let a = [{ employees: { employee: [{ id: "1", firstName: "Tom", lastName: "Cruise" }, { id: "2", firstName: "Maria", lastName: "Sharapova" }, { id: "3", firstName: "James", lastName: "Bond" }] } }];
var b = [{ name: '', grade: 'x' }, { name: 'yaya', grade: 'x' }, { name: 'x', frade: 'd' }, { name: 'a', grade: 'b' }];


function findIt(arr, searchKey) {
  let reg = new RegExp(':(.*?)' + searchKey, 'g');
  return arr.filter(obj => reg.test(JSON.stringify(obj)));
}

console.log("I found: ", findIt(a, "James")); // breaks

console.log("I found: ", findIt(a[0].employees.employee, "James")); // breaks

console.log("I found: ", findIt(b, "yaya")); // works fine
```